# OpenLayers 3 WMS layer to canvas

Tags: wms, openlayers, openlayers-2, html5, mapcanvas

I am taking the context and taking it to a canvas which was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30872633/openlayers-3-tile-canvas-context) and the answer can be found in [this JSfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/iblasi/Lkc1L0an/).

[image]

However, I am looking to load a WMS layer from geoserver and extract only this WMS layer to make a process and display something on canvas.
On Openlayers 2 it could be done with [layerContainerDiv](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.layerContainerDiv) extracting the element that contains all the layers and taking the required one.
But it seems that in Openlayers 3 cannot be done. I have tried something similar to [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/iblasi/gw4e4zh4/) (take into account that this example gives a cross-origin error, but not in my server), but without success as all the layers are processed and cannot be distinguished.

[image]

Does someone know how can layers can be distinguished or separated to process them independently?

I found the [Layer Spy Example](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/layer-spy.html) which it seems that making use of `precompose` and `postcompose` could be a possibility, but  using the options of [ol.Map](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.Map.html) I can find the 2 layers by `map.getLayers().getLength()`. And I can find the array of the WMS with `map.getLayers().getArray()[0]` but how to take the layer context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at the [Shaded Relief sample](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/examples/shaded-relief.html)?

It uses `operation` from [ol.source.Raster](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.source.Raster.html). They enable data processing on raster (your WMS is a raster)

Like with `precompose`/`precompose`, you can also set some functions on raster with `afteroperations`/`beforeoperations` from [ol.source.RasterEvent.html](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.source.RasterEvent.html)

Comment: the example as you said, it is a raster, but I am also trying it with a XYZ tile for different zooms. Is there any similar event for these kind of layers? As I [checked](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.source.html), it doesn't seem to be possible. Is there any other way?

Comment: An `ol.source.Raster` can use an `ol.source.XYZ` if you look again at the Shaded Relief sample mentioned before. So, not need to look elsewhere for other events: just use `ol.source.Raster` or otherwise I missed the point maybe.

Comment: @thomasg77it works! Very good example the "Shaded Relief" which shows exactly how operations can be done on a layer. Thank you.